# Connections not successfully closed?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jdbc

During the last days one of our applications started to fail after I uploaded the newest version of my software to our server.
It accesses some of the shared tables but I'm unable to figure out if I am doing something wrong and if it's my fault or not.

In my test-environment everything worked out fine, but during I updated my tables on the main server I recognized some of them appeared to be locked like in the case there was still an operation pending.

After killing my processes in the Activity Monitor everything was fine again. Which was a bit weird. I am using plain JDBC and sometimes Hibernate for my operations.
I checked it several times and I always handle JDBC-Connections like this:

```
Connection c = null;
Statement s = null;//Sometimes PreparedStatement
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
//OPERATIONS
}
catch{
//Handling
}finally{
Mycon.disconnect(rs,ps,c);
}
```

The Mycon-Class is a static class which just supports such basic stuff...

```
public static void disconnect(ResultSet resultSet, PreparedStatement ps, Connection connection) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            } // nothing we can do
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            } // nothing we can do
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            } // nothing we can do
        }
    }
```

For Hibernate it's easier usually. Then I just use a simple:

```
try{
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session hsession = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = hsession.beginTransaction();
//Operations
tx.commit;
}catch(...){}
finally{
try{
hsession.close;
}catch(...){}
}
```

I use Apache Tomcat 7 for the handling of my connections, so I thought there's no need to worry about connections.

Anyway - there are for example 4 processes of mine:

[image: Server_Monitor_View]

The first and the second one are just from the Server-Manager.

## 3 Shows in its details:

```
SELECT W_ID, Comment, Date FROM Buran.dbo.Object WHERE right(convert(varchar, Date, 106), 8) like ''
```

Which shouldn't be there in my opinion. I used this statement several times withing another statement but closed it:

```
innerstat = null;
inners = null;
innerswert = "";
try {
    innerstat = c.createStatement();
    inners = innerstat.executeQuery("SELECT W_ID, Comment, Date FROM Buran.dbo.Object WHERE right(convert(varchar, Date, 106), 8) like '" + innerswert + "'");

    while (inners.next()) {
        innerswert = inners.getString(1);
        out.write("<option value='" + inners.getInt("W_ID") + "'>");
        out.write(innerswert);
        out.write("</option>");
    }
} catch (SQLException sqle2) {
    out.write(sqle2.toString());
    out.write(sqle2.getLocalizedMessage());
    sqle2.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    Mycon.disconnect(inners, innerstat);
}
```

Am I just interpreting things which aren't there? The serverlogs are fine and my code works as it should without throwing exceptions. What do you think might be the mistake (if there is any?)

Comment: you don't close `c` in your last code sample. Where does your connections come from, are you using a pool? Is the number of connection you see growing or it just stick to 2?

Comment: Nah, the last one is fine, I needed to re-use c to open the connections for those inner statements. c is closed in the end together with the outer ones.
Sorry, I don't get the 2nd question, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean how do you get/open a new `Connection`

Comment: I just obtain it from the Apache-Server (same for Hibernate):
`public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/sqlserv");
        return ds.getConnection();

    }`

Comment: Well, is this behavior usual? I mean that the process remains even due to a already closed connection.

Comment: @RC. That `DataSource` could actually be backed with a connection pool.